# Office for Mac Actions not showing in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, office-2016

I have both Office 2011 and Office 2016 installed on my Mac. I also have Parallels and the windows version of MSFT Office. I need to automate some work and need to use the scripts that are bundled with the Office for Mac 2011 version. I am running Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F1808)

When I enter automator I see the scripts, but they point to the Parallels versions of Office:

[image: Automator view]

I have already researched where are this scripts stored: /Library/Automator
I have disabled in Parallels "Share Windows Applications with Mac"
Automator is set to open these scripts (obviously):
[image: file info]

Comment: My wife and I both have employer-issued 2016 MacBook Pros with full Office installed.  On my computer, I can see the automator actions for Word, Excel, etc (especially when I organize actions by application), but on my wife's computer they are not visible.  I built the workflow on mine and she imported it on hers, but it still won't work.  So someone... help??